# Count number of time a class method is called in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, counter, class-method

There is already a topic there showing how to count the number of times a instance method is called within the program:
[Count the number of times a method is called in Cocoa-Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190297/count-the-number-of-times-a-method-is-called-in-cocoa-touch)

The code described there is working well with an instance method, but it isn't working with a class method. Somebody knows how to do ?

Comment: You can use a `static int` if I recall correctly

Comment: What "isn't working"? You might need to read the [ask] and [faq]

Comment: No need to be so rude James, your comment is very arrogant. I edited my post though, because it's true it wasn't clear enough, although everybody but you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `static int`:

```
+(void)myClassMethod{
  static int count = 0;
  count++;

  //your code
}
```

**Edit**: This is pretty stupid now I think of it since you can't retrieve the count from outside the method.
Still you can log it or send the value with a notification or any other way...

**Edit 2**:
Or you could use another class method to store your counter:

```
+(int)countAfterIncrement:(BOOL)increment{
  static int count = 0;
  if (increment)
    count ++;
  return count;
}

+(void)myClassMethod{
      [MyClass countAfterIncrement:YES];

      //your code
 }
```

To retrieve the value just use `[MyClass countAfterIncrement:NO];`

Comment: Well, if you just need to log it, it should be ok. You could also send his number (notification, etc.)